# Macro Express External Script: HTA/HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a macro with Macro Express using the enternal script: HTA/HTML.
It will open a site inside another window, but with the current code the macro keeps running instead of going onto the next part of the macro. Here is what I have (%vartitle% and %varsite% are set prior to the external script [%varsite% of course being the URL]).

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>%vartitle%</title>
<hta:application
id = "ExampleHTA"
singleInstance = "yes"
icon = "macexp.ico"
border = "thin"
minimizeButton = "yes"
maximizeButton = "yes"
scroll = "yes" />
</head>

<BODY>
<iframe src="%varsite%" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just happened to see this question.

From what I am reading, your problem is the macro waits for the HTA script to finish before moving on to its next line of code.

The **External Script** command will *NOT* move on until the script finishes, and in this case, it will not move on until the URL closes.

However ...

You can have MXPro do what you want by using a different command called **Program Launch**.  "mshta.exe" would be the program to launch and the fullpath HTA file would be placed in the *Program Parameters* field.

In order to have MXPro move right along after launching the mshta.exe, simply leave the *Capture Console Output* checkbox clear ... unchecked.